# protractor not working with Safari 11

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, safaridriver

protractor version : 5.0.1
safari version : 11
Mac version : 10.13
selenium version : 3.0.1

Error message: safaridriver could not launch because it is not configured

I have enabled the safari driver using the command --enable  but still it is not launching the browser

Any possible solutions for the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of times, it's because the developer option to allow remote automation isn't clicked. In safari, you can access this by clicking 'preferences' -> advanced. At the bottom it says 'show Developer Menu in Menu Bar.' Click that. Then in the newly appeared develop tab click on 'Allow Remote Automate' towards the bottom of the list. If this doesn't run it, post your code and we can take a more thorough look.